# Is it possible to map Data Views to Data Extensions in attribute group?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder, data-views

I have created a Attribute Group in Contacts Builder. I have a Data extension with customers(contactID, name, email).

Can I link Data Views in Attribute groups? Is it possible to do so? I want to link _Subscriber data view

Also, can I add a filter to Data Views in automation studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those things are not possible with the data views.

However, nothing stops you from simply setting up "mirror" data extensions for each relevant data view (DV), which you periodically (say, daily) fill with the Data view contents using SQL.

This can also be used to circumvent the built-in restriction in the DVs to hold only 6 months of data. So it can almost be considered a "general best practice". With the mirror DEs, you can absolutely do everything that you planned to do.